# jQuery Dialog moveToTop Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

jQuery UI v1.10 seems to have an issue with stacking multiple dialogs on a page where it will refresh all open dialogs when any dialog is clicked.

Here are some fiddles. Using the same code:

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class='d' data-isrc='http://www.slashdot.org'>
</div>
<div id="div2" class='d' data-isrc='http://www.cnn.com'>
</div>
```

JS

```
var opts = {
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    autoOpen: true,
    open: function(){
        var src = $(this).data("isrc"),
            $iframe = $("<iframe seamless='seamless' src='" + src + "'>");

        console.log(src);
        $(this).append($iframe);

    }
};
$("#div1").dialog(opts);

$("#div2").dialog(opts);
```

This fiddle is using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQueryUI 1.9.2, and behaves how I need it: http://jsfiddle.net/REmJb/

This fiddle is using jQuery 2.0.2 and jQueryUI 1.10.3, and shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UBV4v/

How can I make the above link work smoothly [without refreshing] on the newer jQuery framework?

*ETA:*
It seems this gets tracked down to a new approach on the `insertBefore()` method. Quoting [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

> **Before jQuery 1.9**, the append-to-single-element case did not create a
>   new set, but instead returned the original set which made it difficult
>   to use the .end() method reliably when being used with an unknown
>   number of elements.

... but the issue is not present for v1.9 so perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I added to my scripts to disable this behaviour.

```
jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype._moveToTop = function(event, silent) {
    return true;
};
```

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826296/jquery-ui-1-10-dialog-prevent-insertbefore/21827946#21827946)